# Using prepaid credits in iOS apps

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

we are developing an iPhone app as an extension of a classifieds system (web site). On that web site users can buy (prepaid) credits and use them to boost and promote their ads. Will Apple reject our app if we implement consumption of credits? We are not gonna allow buying the credits, just using them (users will still have to buy credits on the web site).

Only worrying thing I found is item 11.2 in App Store review guidelines:

> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be
>   rejected.

Is there a way to contact Apple directly regarding this question?

And a add-on question. I suppose we can implement a payment gateway system like Amazon and Ebay and get a way with buying credits? I don't see any restrictions in guidelines regarding non in-app purchase system.

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful, please click the checkmark next to it to mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: No worries bro, I actually contacted Apple regarding this question and I'm still waiting on their response. When I get it I'll paste it here. If Apples response is something other then Siba said I'll mark my response as answer, if not I'll mark Siba as the mr. Correcto! :)

Comment: What did Apple do finally, rejected or accepted? Please share...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In-app purchase" is only required to purchase content or extra-functionality or extra feature or to remove any type of limitations inside the application. To achieve these things you shouldn't use any other external purchase mechanism (per App Store review guidelines §11.2).

In your application, the user will only use the available credits which are already bought on your website, so there is not an issue, although you shouldn't provide any type of link to your website inside your application.

Comment: "you shouldn't provide any type of link to your website inside your application" means that we should not stimulate user to leave the app and buy additional credits via a link. Is it OK to say "you do not have additional credits, please add some more on XY" where XY is the name of the brand?

Comment: Yes, You can Show them A Alert , You can Create a profile Page Where user can Able to see their credit balance.

Answer (score 1):

Genererally *"will Apple reject this if..."*-questions can only be answered as such:

Apple does as they like. If they feel this in some way breaks the review guidelines, they will reject it and tell you, but you have no way of knowing for sure until you have submitted the actual app. In your case, I can't see why they would ban it, as you are not able to use real money within the actual app, but as I said, you don't know.

If you want to try to get an answer from Apple, you can try to contact them from [this page](https://developer.apple.com/contact/).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got an answer from Apple. It took a while and it wasn't worth a wait. I think Siba was right, but I'll get back to you after we submit our app just to verify everything.

Apple replied:

> Thank you for taking the time to contact us about your app design and concept questions. I understand that you would like to know if you
>   implement consumption credits into your app would be acceptable for
>   your app.
>
> While we cannot pre-approve apps, we can address compliance questions
>   about specific App Store Review Guidelines or sections of the iOS
>   Developer Program License Agreement (PLA). I understand that this may
>   be a little frustrating and I apologize for any inconvenience this may
>   cause, however, we may only answer specific questions concerning the
>   following resources, unless the app is submitted for review so that we
>   may test the functionality.

Comment: I'm thinking of doing the same thing. Did you manage to get your app through the review? My guess is that Apple WILL REJECT it as they are missing profit if the credits are not bought through the Apple Store (so, not through In App Purchases).

Comment: Our app is live, and it passed Apple's review. That doesn't mean that your app will pass a review test; it just means ours did.

Our payment options are: 

- web option leads a user to the in-app browser where we just open a payment gateway and user inputs all required data
- sms starts a new message with prepopulated data
- "manual" payment just shows instructions on "how to" (bank transaction)

We do not use IAP or any Apple payment system. User can also spend credits inside the app. Note: it's not a gaming app, it's a craigslist kind of app